# VBA Excel: Search Sheet for partial string, then take row and paste into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new at `VBA` and I need a little help writing a code to perform a specific function.

I need to be able to search column "**B**" for a partial string, and output the row into another sheet.

For example, 
I need to pull all the rows that have the word "**MOTOR**" as part of the string in column "**B**" and paste those rows in "**sheet 2**" The sting in column "**B**" could have a variety of strings such as "**TEFCMOTOR286B2**" or "**MOTORSLIDEBASE286B2**" and I need to copy both of the rows with the previous strings and make them into a list on "**sheet 2**" The number of Rows that need to be copied will vary and sometimes there wont be any with the partial string "**MOTOR**" at all.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for the *Macro Recorder*

1. switch on the *Recorder*
2. place an *AutoFilter* on the original data
3. Using *AutoFilter* pick **Text Filters > Contains...**
4. copy the visible rows and paste to the other sheet
5. switch off the *Recorder*

Comment: I'm trying to set this up so I can use the same template for multiple jobs. The problem I'm running into with the recorder is when I copy the visible rows over it locks me into copying over the specific rows that are on that workbook. If my motor goes from row 4 in one workbook to row 5 in the next workbook the Macro still wants to copy row 4 even though it was able to filter out the right results, So it isn't copying the right row. Not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you are copying from Sheet1 to Sheet2.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransferMotor()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strValue As String
    Dim lngRowOutput As Long

    ' where does the data end in Sheet1
    lngLastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If lngLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data

    ' Clear down sheet2, assume we have column headings in row 1 we want to keep
    Sheet2.Range("2:1048576").Clear

    lngRowOutput = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet2 when we find a "MOTOR" phrase

    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        strValue = Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value ' get value from column B

        If InStr(1, strValue, "MOTOR", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' can we find "MOTOR" in the text
            Sheet1.Rows(lngRow).Copy
            Sheet2.Rows(lngRowOutput).PasteSpecial
            lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
        End If

    Next lngRow



End Sub
```

Comment: The sheets are actually called "Parts Tracking Sheet" and "Assy Kit Creation" I'm trying to take the Data from "Parts Tracking Sheet" to create the "Assy Kit Creation" Sheet. The Data on the "PTS" would end somewhere between row 50 and row 80. Yes I would want to keep the headings in row 1. I want to write the values to columns A-D in the 2nd sheet.

Comment: that's not what your original question said...it said you wanted to copy the rows, not just 4 columns (a to d) and no mention of the sheet names was provided.  I still think you can work my code into your solution with some minor changes.  Please specify the question in the level of detail you require the answer to rather than letting people answer and then state your real requirement ;-)